# Custom scroll bar for chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I need to convert IE custom scroll bar into chrome.
here is css

```
scrollbar-face-color: #EAEAEA;
scrollbar-shadow-color: #EAEAEA;
scrollbar-highlight-color: #EAEAEA;
scrollbar-3dlight-color: silver;
scrollbar-darkshadow-color: silver;
scrollbar-track-color: #F8F6F7;
scrollbar-arrow-color: #6E6D6D;
```

Can anyone convert this to chrome exactly?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried ?? Have you searched about crossbrowser custom scrollbar?

Comment: I think it is not possible that way, because these customizable scroll bars are, to my knowledge, a "feature" only supported by IE.

Comment: Danko, I have tried for chrome scrollbar, but i am unable to map the exact.
http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-webkit-vertical-scrollbars/

Comment: @Abrixas2 We can customize scrollbar in chrome too but with different properties. The problem is mapping the properties.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised this isn't a duplicate question, but didn't have much luck finding anything that matched.

Comment: @sirajhussain You may notice that this question is getting downvoted.  This is because you have posted a question with a problem without posting code demonstrating what you already attempted to do to solve the problem.  In general, SO questions are best received when they show a best effort was put forth at resolving a problem before bringing it to SO.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're referring to is (to my knowledge) a non-standardized feature. That being said, custom scrollbars used to be popular on the web, and as a result [Chrome still supports them from its Webkit days](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/css/CSSSelector.cpp&l=290). The approach you take in Chrome is slightly different, using pseudo-elements rather than properties:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar              {  }
::-webkit-scrollbar-button       {  }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track        {  }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  {  }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb        {  }
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner       {  }
::-webkit-resizer                {  }
```

You can read more about these in the article [*Custom Scrollbars in WebKit*](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/). The properties won't necessarily match 1-to-1 with the Webkit pseudo-elements, but you should be able to find a nice degree of overlap.